# Magento 2.2 composer installation with ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, magento, composer-php, magento2

So i run composer in magento root folder after few minutes of installation it ends with [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP0Nk.png)

Is all of this packages are required to use magento and why it doesnt ask for keys.

Comment: What do you mean with "why it doesnt ask for keys"? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

These packages are merely suggested by the package creators. The creators can specify the packages it suggests and the text that is shown.

Example:

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "monolog/monolog": "Allows more advanced logging of the application flow",
        "ext-xml": "Needed to support XML format in class Foo"
    }
}
```

These packages are not required to run Magento. Looks like your composer install was successful.